# Any Javascript DateTime Function return MySQL datetime format?

Tags: javascript, datetime, timezone

I've a function that send ajax request to a server file with parameters. Problem is i want to send current DateTime value to compare it from database.

as MySQL datatime format all datetimes are shown as "2012-02-03 19:50:28" format.

How can i generate it in Javascript.

Another question: Can i add hours to current datetime (to fix server time zone problem)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try this

```
/* use a function for the exact format desired... */
function ISODateString(d){
  function pad(n){return n<10 ? '0'+n : n}
  return d.getUTCFullYear()+'-'
      + pad(d.getUTCMonth()+1)+'-'
      + pad(d.getUTCDate()) +' '
      + pad(d.getUTCHours())+':'
      + pad(d.getUTCMinutes())+':'
      + pad(d.getUTCSeconds())
}

var d = new Date();
console.log(ISODateString(d)); // prints something like 2009-09-28 19:03:12
```

Refernece:
[date format](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format)
[date type in javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)
[working with dates](http://www.elated.com/articles/working-with-dates/)

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
Date.prototype.toMysqlFormat = function () {
    function pad(n) { return n < 10 ? '0' + n : n }
    return this.getFullYear() + "-" + pad(1 + this.getMonth()) + "-" + pad(this.getDate()) + " " + pad(this.getHours()) + ":" + pad(this.getMinutes()) + ":" + pad(this.getSeconds());
};
var TimeNow = new Date().toMysqlFormat();
alert(TimeNow); //Alerts Current TimeStamp
```

Answer (score 1):

Parse date to your format string, you can do it by the [Date API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) or use [Datejs](http://datejs.com) (a powerful date plugin).

But I recommend you push millisecond number to server/mysql instead of string :

```
new Date().getTime();
```