# Javascript datetime format in database format

Tags: javascript

Please how do I format a today's date in javascript so it will output something like '2013-05-24 03:21:12' that i can insert into database datetime field.? Thanks in advance..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Formatting a date in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/formatting-a-date-in-javascript)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9138820/any-javascript-datetime-function-return-mysql-datetime-format this might do it what you want...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dates? Times? Give [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) a shot

Answer (score 0):

```
dateToString : function (unformatted) {
  if (!unformatted) {
    return null;
  }
  var year = unformatted.getFullYear();
  var month = unformatted.getMonth() + 1;
  var day = unformatted.getDate();
  if (month < 10) {
    month = '0' + month;
  }
  if (day < 10) {
    day = '0' + day;
  }
  return [year, month, day].join('-');
}
```

feel free to add time formatting